# How to unit test a method has multi inner call protected/private method by phpunit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mocking, phpunit

I am newbie at unit test. 
My test environment is PHPUnit on Laravel.

I want to know how to unit test a method has multi call protected/private method by PHPUnit?

Those protected/private method not only return expected value but also throw exception when fail.

[example.php](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a757fa84e2a7a1d724c481613f56661c) and [ExampleTest.php](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7ffe72dedbb6cd29d4ff2e13e2bbd22b).

The important question is :if I want to test method2 or method3 throwsexception, I need pass prev protected/private method(method1 or method1+method2), is this ok? Or any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are bent on having your private methods throw exceptions like that which the public method does not catch, then they must throw custom exceptions and not the generic `\Exception` (It's actually a good practice). So then in your tests you can just expect the custom exception to be thrown.

Then generally speaking, I think it's better design-wise for the constructor itself to check existence of the args and just throw at construction time if the public method will always be called, or for the public method to make those checks. It'll limit the number of throwing going around.

PHPUnit author's thoughts on testing private method - https://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html

Comment: Of course I made a custom exception and throw then any model not found.
I just confused with a method depend on multi method/class to get result, mock by mock is a good way or and better idea?